# Calcular o número de elementos com CSS

Tags: html, css3

Estou fazendo uma lista numerada com contadores regressivos usando o [`counter-reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset). Atualmente coloco o número de items da lista manualmente:

```
.faq { counter-reset:my-counter 2; }
.faq dt { counter-increment: my-counter -1; }
.faq dt:before { content: counter(my-counter, decimal-leading-zero) "."; }
```

Com o HTML:

```
<dl class="faq">    
    <dt>Item 1</dt>
    <dt>Item 2</dt>
</dl>
```

Imprime:

> `01. Item 1`
>   `00. Item 2`

Mas, se acrescentar um `<dt>` e não ajustar o `counter-reset`, vai imprimir:

> `01. Item 1`
>   `00. Item 2`
>   `-01. Item 3`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/Lex8v4cd/).

Li [*Can CSS detect the number of children an element has?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8720931/1287812) e tentei `counter-reset:my-counter ~ dt`, mas na realidade não entendi muito bem o uso do `~`.

Sei que posso fazer com jQuery

```
var reset = 'my-counter '+ $('.faq dt').length;
$('.faq').css( 'counter-reset', reset );
```

É possível com CSS puro?

<sup>Referência: [*Numbering In Style | CSS-Tricks*](http://css-tricks.com/numbering-in-style/)</sup>

Comment: Essa resposta que do SOEn funciona vendo se o enésimo elemento `li` existe e aplicando a regra tanto a ele quanto aos [_siblings_](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) dele. Infelizmente acho que não tem jeito de obter um número só usando css, você vai ter que usar magic number mesmo (talvez usando pre-processadores de css role, mas ai já não sei dizer)

Comment: Verificando a documentação na MDN notei que o CSS Counter tem três propriedades, sendo estas:

- counter
- counter-increment
- counter-reset

Pelo visto o counter reset realiza o reset para 0, neste caso o que pode ser feito é exibir usando CSS a lista na ordem inversa.

Comment: Corrigindo, resetando para o inteiro desejado.
Neste caso usando CSS pode-se exibir a lista na ordem inversa a que ela está no DOM, alcançando assim o efeito desejado.

Comment: Uai, ooredroxoo, se puder confirmar sua teoria e publicar uma resposta, fantástico.

Comment: Pesquisei um pouco e acho que não dá mesmo. Eu suspeito que o CSS não tenha como saber isso, ele incrementa o contador quando encontra cada elemento, então só sabe o total depois de passar por todos.

Comment: Pior que numa `<ol>` seria extremamente simples (exceto pelo IE talvez): http://www.impressivewebs.com/reverse-ordered-lists-html5/

Comment: Acho que o que o ooredroxoo quis dizer foi algo similar a [isso aqui](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20879/21700): Usar o css para inverter a lista na raça

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há uma forma de fazer, usando transformações CSS (`transform`), como descobri no [StackOverflow <sup>(inglês)</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918693/reverse-the-order-of-divs-children), com alguns contras:

- não é compatível com todos os browsers: [Can I use CSS Transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- tive qua adicionar algum markup ao seu original, então acho que quebrei um pouco a semântica... uns `div`s, em torno de cada grupo `dt`+`dd`.
- a seleção de texto, fica com problemas, pois o browser acha que o que está em baixo, vem antes no fluso de seleção

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## A solução

```css
.faq {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
.faq > * {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
.faq {
  counter-reset: my-counter 0;
}
.faq dd {
  margin: 0 0 50px;
}
.faq dt:before {
  content: counter(my-counter, decimal-leading-zero)".";
  font: bold 50px/1 Sans-Serif;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}
.faq dt,
.faq dd {
  padding-left: 90px;
}
.faq dt {
  counter-increment: my-counter 1;
  font: bold 16px Georgia;
  padding: 4px 0 10px 90px;
  position: relative;
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<dl class="faq">
  <div>
    <dt>Como colocar o umbigo pra dentro?</dt>
    <dd>Aperte o umbago com o dedão. Fonte: Wikipedia.</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Onde eu baixo um processador dual core?</dt>
    <dd>AMD ou IBM?</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Carne vermelha faz mal, carne branca faz mal, o que devo comer?</dt>
    <dd>Carne humana.</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Quando devo falar sobre sexo com meu cachorro?</dt>
    <dd>Quando ele entrar na puberdade.</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

### Como funciona?

O princípio consta em inverter o sistema de coordenadas verticais, usando transformações CSS:

```
transform: scaleY(-1)
```

Isso vai inverter o eixo Y, que é tradicionalmente o eixo vertical.

Então passo a passo, isso é o que ocorre:

1. Se aplicarmos essa transformação apenas uma vez, então, o que acontece é que tudo dentro do elemento com o estilo aplicado fica de cabeça para baixo. No caso, primeiro aplicamos a transformação ao elemento que engloba toda a lista:

   [image: Invertendo o elemento mestre]
2. Acontece que agora, cada um dos sub-elementos está de cabaça para baixo. Então o que temos que fazer, é inverter cada um deles individualmente, o que na prática os desinverterá:

   [image: Invertendo os sub-elementos]

Comment: Pra quem quiser um [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masbicudo/osct3Lwc/).

Comment: O truque é então inverter o Y de cada `div`? O que exatamente o `scaleY(-1)` está fazendo? Porque a escala inverte a posição? . . . . Follow up no [philosophy.se]: *"Is there any limit to human creativity?"* :)

Comment: Hahaha, belo truque, agora eu entendi. @brasofilo É uma lista crescente, mas flipada duplamente (primeiro o container, depois cada item), dando o efeito de regressiva.

Comment: @bfavaretto, yes, lá no SO tem a explicação do código: `mirror in the vertical axis both the container and the childs. The childs follow the inverted y axis of the container, but the children themselves are again head up`. Acho curioso que seja `scale` que faz o truque.

Comment: Essas perguntas são tão *wtf* quanto a solução. +1

Comment: Adicionei uma explicação com algumas imagens pra facilitar a visualização. As imagens tão meio toscas... to num computador que só tem Paint... mas já dá pra ter uma noção visual.